# To "make" a draw

Tags: grammaticality, grammar, phrases

I often hear professional chess players use the phrase "to make a draw" where I would simply use "to draw" or replace "to make" with "to bring about" (or any of [its synonyms](http://thesaurus.com/browse/bring%20about)) if we really had to use "draw" as a noun here.

For example, [here's](http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_detailpage&v=LUjEtIUuAj4#t=56) (time: 0:57) Fabiano Caruana (a native English speaker, mind you) using this phrase as below:

> "...I don't know if White has real winning chances, but I felt I
>   should be able to make a draw."

Is this phrase correct?

Comment: Also keep in mind that sometimes in chess, a draw is something that you aim for. Unlike most other games/sports, there are cases where a player will want and try hard to achieve a draw.

Answer (score 6):

The word *make* can mean "to achieve or attain" (see [Definition 10 in this dictionary](http://education.yahoo.com/reference/dictionary/entry/make)).

So, the quote could be paraphrased as:

> *I don't believe that White can win the game, but all is not lost: it seems White can still achieve a draw*.

In other words, I don't think there's anything wrong with this quote.

More importantly, many sports have their own way to commonly phrase things. In chess, *make a draw* is an oft-used way to describe the tactic of playing for a draw, particularly when you are at a disadvantage. For example:

> “I made a mistake and I had to sacrifice a piece. After that I had to **make a draw**,” said Grandmaster Valentin Yotov.<sup>[1](http://susanpolgar.blogspot.com/2012_04_02_archive.html)</sup>
>
> In reality though, we sometimes find ourselves in a situation in which we need to **make a draw**.<sup>[2](http://www.chess.com/article/view/playing-for-a-draw2)</sup>
>
> If White doesn't risk anything, he cannot lose! Controlling the game, he can always **make a draw** from a position of strength.<sup>[3](http://newandfeatured.blogspot.com/2013/06/discounted-selling-price-sicilian.html)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

‘Make’ has various meanings in the context of games, and one is to secure a certain score. This seems to be the meaning here.

Answer (score -3):

What about the sentence from the text : 'She is making a draw and talking to her father.'
It seems that the phrase 'make a draw' has the meaning 'do nothing'.